# when i delete row it keeps coming back when i load again

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, delete-row

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Delete Button

Dim mydataset As New DataSet
Dim mydataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Try
        Dim int As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index

        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0))
        mydataset.Tables(0).Rows(int).Delete()
        mydataAdapter.Update(mydataset, "datainfo")
        MessageBox.Show("Success!")

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a webform app - at which point are you populating the dataGridView?

Comment: you need to commit the deletion in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't use mydataAdapter.Update(mydataset, "datainfo") 
2) Try using SqlCommandBuilder as below:

```
Dim ESCBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(mydataAdapter)
ESCBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
da.UpdateCommand = ESCBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
da.Update(mydataset)
```

3) try to read almost everything about [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. Hope it helps